# How to use the absolute path of a file on another hard drive with Oracle (sqlplus)?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am surprised I did not find anything about this anywhere, but how do I execute a file with sqlplus with the absolute path of the file? In the internet it says

```
sqlplus databaseURL @sqlFile
```

This works if I use it as relative File and have the SQL File in the same directory. But using a path after the "@" just doesn't work and it says "file does not exist" when I run the command. The file surely is in the specified path and I am on Windows.

How do I make this work?

EDIT: Example of relative path:

```
sqlplus -l user/pw@localhost:1521/service @test.sql;
```

Example of absolute path

```
sqlplus -l user/pw@localhost:1521/service @D:/folder/test.sql;
```

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please share example of relative and absolute path by editing the post.

Comment: In windows it should be `D:\folder\test.sql`

Comment: That still does not work. In the sqlplus command line it says that the file could not be opened..

Comment: you need to provide path  as string. Try  `sqlplus -l user/pw@localhost:1521/service @"D:\folder\test.sql";`

Comment: Now it says that the file "" cant be found :(

Comment: Command should run with sqlplus.exe with or without quotes because there is no space character in file name (successfully tested with Oracle Instant Client 19.6 on Windows 2019). What is the exact SQPLus version ? Are you sure that given file exists and is readable by user running SQLPlus ?

Comment: I have Oracle Instant Client 19.6 and Windows 10 aswell (Newest update). The exact version is 19.6.0.0.0. About the being able to read the file thing: I copied the file into the local folder and it worked. I am not aware of any permission restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to clarify what the problem for me was, it was actually just in the file itself.. I used "\" instead of "/" at the end of the SQL File. After I changed that, it worked for me. My command looked like this in the end:

```
sqlplus -l user/pw@localhost:1521/service @D:\folder\test.sql;
```

Comment: It's strange because in my environment both separator work.

Comment: It IS strange. But I can reproduce my results with the \. It works after I change that to /.

Comment: Oracle works with either slashes on windows ,try to use different slashes in path it will still work

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility: to set the SQLPATH environment variable to specify where SQL*Plus should look for SQL files:

[Doc. says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/configuring-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-D7479120-872F-4E47-AC13-B1B07DF69A46)

> The SQLPATH registry entry specifies the location of SQL scripts.
>   SQL*Plus searches for SQL scripts in the current directory and then in
>   the directories specified by the SQLPATH registry entry, and in the
>   subdirectories of SQLPATH directories.
>
> The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0 registry subkey (or the HOMEn directory for the associated ORACLE_HOME) contains the
>   SQLPATH registry entry. SQLPATH is created with a default value of
>   ORACLE_HOME\DBS. You can specify any directories on any drive as valid
>   values for SQLPATH.
>
> When setting the SQLPATH registry entry, you can concatenate directories with a semicolon (;). For example:
>
> ```
> c:\oracle\ora12\database;c:\oracle\ora12\dbs
> ```
>
> See the Registry Editor's help system for instructions on how to edit the SQLPATH registry entry.

Comment: That's because Oracle Instant Client has no ORACLE_HOME registered in Windows Registry. Not sure this can work with Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: @NuTa  On windows you can set `SQLPATH` in system or user variables

Comment: @Sam I did that and it did not recognize anything or work for me. The thing in my answer works.

Comment: I use it all the time on Windows and Linux.If you set correctly it should work,to test it from command prompt type `echo %SQLPATH%` it should display as `D:\folder` or wherever your sql scripts are